# MySQL fields to (ex)change a values

Tags: mysql

I have a table `dates` with columns:

date1 (monday, this week)
date2 (wednesday, this week)
date3 (**wednesday, next week**)
date4 (**monday, next week**)

What I would need to do... I want when this week go away (after weekend), to  switch value of date4 to date1 and value of date3 to date2, since "next" week will became a "this" week, after weekend.

Can someone please give me a dirrections, I was trying to do it manually, but it was a really bad code.

Comment: You should - if at all possible - work with a different table design. For example: Have a table with a proper datetime column in it for holding the actual date and then write some type of *pivot* code to make record entries with particular datetime values appear in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simple answer .... set value of date3 to date1, and delete value of date 3. Simple as that.